# Как лучше определить условие для пагинации? Typescript, Angular

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular2, typescript

Здравствуйте, есть пагинация типа "Подгрузить еще", которая принимает такие числа: номер текущей страницы; общее количество итемов в списке, к которому применяется пагинация; число итемов, которое выводится на странице.

Вот я думал сделать следующим образом:

```
 if([номер текущей страницы] + 1 < [общее количество итемов] / [Количество итемов, что выводятся на странице]) {
   // код
}
```

Но это не решает случая, когда общее число итемов, деленное на количество итемов что выводятся на странице, - будет не целым. 
Честно говоря с таким очень редко сталкиваюсь и что-то вообще в голову не приходит как такое сделать можно, подскажите пожалуйста)

Comment: Вам нужно узнать текущий номер страницы?

Comment: Что значит _число будет не целым_? Количество айтемов не может быть дробным

Comment: @Vitalii , мне нужно узнать будут ли итемы на следующей странице, или это будет пустая страница

Comment: @AGS17 , да, не правильно выразился, поменял вопрос, там может быть не целым общее число итемов, деленное на число итемов что выводятся на 1й странице

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var items1 = 0;
var items2 = 1;
var items3 = 5;
var items4 = 76;
var items5 = 77;

function isSomethingLeft(currentPage, itemsPerPage, items) {
  if (!items) return false;
  return (items - currentPage * itemsPerPage) / itemsPerPage > 0

}

console.log(isSomethingLeft(1, 4, items1));
console.log(isSomethingLeft(1, 4, items2));
console.log(isSomethingLeft(1, 4, items3));
console.log(isSomethingLeft(1, 4, items4));
console.log(isSomethingLeft(19, 4, items4));
console.log(isSomethingLeft(19, 4, items5));
console.log(isSomethingLeft(3, 30, 107));
console.log(isSomethingLeft(4, 30, 107));
```

Comment: К сожалению там абсолютно та же ошибка что и в моем коде: http://prntscr.com/g49h52 , на 4й странице выдаст false , тоисть на первіх 3х страницах будет по 30 итемов, и оно все правильно выведет, на 4й странице должно быть еще 17 итемов, но для 4й странице ответ будет false, а нада true. Нужно что бы false возвращалось только если на следующей странице будет 0 итемов

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю чего вы хотите. У нас 107 элементов по 30 на странице. Мы на 3 странице. Есть четвертая страница? Да. Теперь идем на 4ую страницу. Есть ли пятая страница? Нет.

Comment: Да, все так и нужно, давайте более наглядно покажу http://prntscr.com/g49ln2 тоисть должно выводится 4 страницы, где на первых 3х по 30 итемов, а на 4й 107, но на 4й странице скрипт вернет false

Comment: На 4ой странице он возвращает false, потому что 5ая страница существовать не должна. На четвертой странице мы покажем 17 айтемов. Зачем нам 5ая страница? Мы же проверяем что? Есть ли следующая страница.

Comment: Ага, все, понял, оочень извиняюсь что туплю) Спасибо большое!